# What is difference onLoad, onDomready, No wrap -in <head> and No wrap -in <body> in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML

```
<select name="skills" class="ui fluid search dropdown" multiple="">
  <option value="">State</option>
  <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
  <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
$('.ui.fluid.search.dropdown')
      .dropdown({
        maxSelections: 3
      });
```

I want use [semantic-ui](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/examples) dropdown. Same code work in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maarifoglu/srqemLvg/) but don't work in my project. When I change Javascript load type **onLoad** and **No wrap -in**  code works in JSFiddle. But I don't know what is it means? How can I apply to my HTML?

> EDIT

Code worked simple html and php, but don't work when options value and text coming from database. this my code: `<select class="ui fluid search dropdown" name="lang_skill[]" id="multi-select" multiple="multiple" > <?php$languages_array =(array)$GLOBALS['obj_selectAndUpdateController']>search_info_languages();$count‌​_languages = count($languages_array);for ($i = 0; $i < $count_languages; $i++) {?><option value="<?php echo $languages_array[$i]['id'] ?>"> <?php echo $languages_array[$i]['description'] ?> </option><?php }?></select> </p>`

> EDIT 2

I fix it, its confilicted with **bootstrap.js**

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait until your DOM is ready, since you're using jQuery, you can use this syntax:

```
$(function() {
   // do your thing
});
```

This would be equivalent to the DomReady property of JSFiddle.

The equivalent to onLoad is to put in the body tag, the "onload" attribute set to a function.

no-wrap in head and in body tells JSFiddle to just drop your code in a script inside of the head or the body, it doesn't work for you because your DOM isn't ready for you to apply the behavior.

Hope I was clear enough.

Comment: Code worked simple html and php, but don't work when options value and text coming from database. this my code:  <select class="ui fluid search dropdown" name="lang_skill[]"  id="multi-select" multiple="multiple" > <?php$languages_array =(array)$GLOBALS['obj_selectAndUpdateController']>search_info_languages();$count_languages = count($languages_array);for ($i = 0; $i < $count_languages; $i++) {?><option value="<?php echo $languages_array[$i]['id'] ?>"> <?php echo $languages_array[$i]['description'] ?> </option><?php }?></select> </p>